# How to validate fields if they aren't serialized in jackson

Tags: java, jackson, jackson-databind

In my class, there's a field I want to validate, but I don't want to return it in the response. For that I've used the annotations

```
@Valid
@JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
private User user;
```

The problem is that when I use WRITE_ONLY, the code doesn't check the validations. What can I do to fix that?

Comment: Here's some info online regarding this: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Spring-Boot, take a look at `@Validated`.